# How to calculate elapsed time in terms of minutes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, function, intervals, subtraction

There is a time stamp column/field in a table, and the format is like

```
2009-12-05 10:35:28,
```

Now I want to get the time in terms of minutes(How many minutes have elapsed) elapsed from then on, how to do it?

Comment: @Steven: you have asked the same question using PHP ....

Comment: But the answers I got are based on PHP, not MySQL. I want to implement this feature using MySQL instead.

Answer (score 11):

[`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) can be used to get a difference between date/time values, which is expressed in a "HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS" format.

[`TIME_TO_SEC()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) can convert this into a number of seconds.

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), my_date_and_timestamp)) / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,your_timestamp_column_name,NOW()) AS minutes_elapsed FROM your_table_name WHERE your_criteria
```